# undefined method `to_sym' for 1:Fixnum or rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am getting the following error for an rspec test but figure out how to fix it:

```
1) Promotion_Check#initialize starts with a list of the rules
   Failure/Error: rules_list = double( { 1 => item_rule, 2 => total_rule } )

   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `to_sym' for 1:Fixnum
   # ./spec/Promotion_Check_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Promotion_Check do


  describe "#initialize" do
    it "starts with a list of the rules" do
      item_rule = double({rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50})
      total_rule = double( {rule_type: "total", total_price_break: 60.00, discount_percentage: 10} )
      rules_list = double( { 1 => item_rule, 2 => total_rule } )
      let(:check) { Promotion_Check.new rules_list }
      expect(check.rules_list).to eq( { 1 => item_rule, 2 => total_rule } )
    end
  end
end
```

And what i will be testing:

```
class Promotion_Check

  attr_reader :rules_list

  def initialize rules_list = {}
    @rules_list = rules_list
  end
end
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-object-double

Comment: Why are you trying to double a bunch of Hashes? Perhaps something deep inside `double` is assuming that you'll only use Hashes with string and symbol keys.

Comment: your right thank you, i fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

fixed with the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Promotion_Check do

  let(:check) { Promotion_Check.new rules_list }
  let(:item_rule) { {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50} }
  let(:total_rule)  { {rule_type: "total", total_price_break: 60.00, discount_percentage: 10} }
  let(:rules_list) { [ 1 => item_rule, 2 => total_rule ] }

  describe "#initialize" do
    it "starts with a list of the rules" do
      expect(check.rules_list).to eq( [ 1 => item_rule, 2 => total_rule ] )
    end
  end
```

Thanks